# mySQL Left Join

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have two tables T1L and T2U. For records matching the `left join`, if `Deleted!=0` I don't want those records from either tables.

```
SELECT
    IF(U.Column1 IS NULL, L.id, -U.id) AS id,
    IF(U.Column1 IS NULL, L.Column1, U.Column1) AS Column1,
    IF(U.Column1 IS NULL, L.Column2, U.Column2) AS Column2,
    IF(U.Column1 IS NULL, L.Deleted, U.Deleted) AS Deleted
FROM
    T1 L
LEFT JOIN T2 U
    ON L.Column1 = U.Column1 AND L.Column2=U.Column2 AND U.Deleted=0
```

If `Deleted!=0`, currently it will give me the record from TI. I don't want that record at all from either TI or T2.

How can I modify the query to achieve that?

Comment: Additionally, you might want to consider the COALESCE() instead of the IF() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move it to the WHERE clause and add an additional check for NULL.

```
SELECT
    IF(U.Column1 IS NULL, L.id, -U.id) AS id,
    IF(U.Column1 IS NULL, L.Column1, U.Column1) AS Column1,
    IF(U.Column1 IS NULL, L.Column2, U.Column2) AS Column2,
    IF(U.Column1 IS NULL, L.Deleted, U.Deleted) AS Deleted
FROM
    T1 L
LEFT JOIN T2 U
    ON L.Column1 = U.Column1 AND L.Column2=U.Column2 
WHERE
    U.Deleted=0
    OR U.Deleted IS NULL
```

Comment: thanks that worked :). I will accept in few minutes when it will allow me to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do properly, you should remove the "AND U.Deleted=0" in the join add a WHERE clause:

```
WHERE U.Deleted=0 OR U.Column1 IS NULL
```